# How to make LiveScript scripts immediately .go() on seen?

Tags: javascript, livescript

(Note: I asked this question on https://github.com/gkz/LiveScript/issues/731 as well)

When I use LiveScript in an html file directly, I have no way to run livescript code immediately on seen. For example;

```
...
<script src="livescript.js"></script>

<div class="my_target"></div>

<script type="text/ls">
# my livescript code will interact with div.my_target
</script>

<script>
/* a javascript code that will interact with div.my_target
</script>

<script type="text/ls">
# my livescript code does something else
</script>

<script>
    var LiveScript = require("LiveScript");
    LiveScript.go();
</script>
```

The LiveScript codes both will run, but the LiveScript code that interacts with `div.my_target` will interact with it **AFTER** the javascript code does, not **BEFORE**

If I define

```
<script>
    var LiveScript = require("LiveScript");
    LiveScript.go();
</script>
```

part everytime right after a LiveScript code defined, then all LiveScript codes till this definition would run more than one time.

```
### livescript code 1
### LiveScript.go()
...
### livescript code 2
### LiveScript.go()
...
### livescript code 3
### LiveScript.go()
...
```

When this code is executed:

- `livescript code 1` will run 3 times, first will run immediately after definition
- `livescript code 2` will run 2 times, first will run immediately after definition
- `livescript code 3` will run 1 time,  this will runimmediately after definition

If it would be this way, LiveScript would be used in html **more easily** and would be used **like a native language of web development**

```
...
<script src="livescript.js"></script>
<script>
    var LiveScript = require("LiveScript");
    LiveScript.doSomeMagic_Kaboooommm();
</script>

...
<script type="text/ls">
# my livescript code
</script>

... more html

<script type="text/ls">
# my livescript code
</script>

...

<script type="text/ls">
# my livescript code
</script>
...
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off compiling the `.ls` files to `.js` and referencing the JavaScript files in your `.html` page.

The `lsc` livescript compiler has options to assist with this such as the `watch(w)` argument combined with the `compile(c)` argument, running `lsc -wc .` will watch all `.ls` files in the current directory and below and compile them whenever you make a change.

For example an `src/index.ls` will compile to `src/index.js`.

I don't think the feature to use LiveScript inline will be supported any time soon.